# Wordpress Advice - Reusable Content

Tags: php, wordpress, content-type

Can I pick your brains please. Everyone seems to have different ideas on reusable content but I'm wondering what is the correct way in my particular case.

I'm building a wordpress site and in the design I have a few 'content blocks' that appear in multiple pages. For example:

- A contact block with map and address etc
- A social links and newsletter subscription block

Whats the best way of doing this?

Personally I'm thinking about it much like the header and footer, build a file with the info in and include it in the template file for that page type.

I don't think I need them as shortcodes as they won't needed to be added to blog posts etc.

Thanks for your thoughts...

Comment: It will be better if you implement a widget for that. Because, you can use that widget everywhere in your theme, you can change widget location in admin panel. I do not suggest to do by including some pages at desired locations.

Comment: You are on the right track, i would use get_template_part https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Yep I think I'm going to go with `get_template_part`. I just read [Understanding get_template_part](http://kovshenin.com/2013/get_template_part/) which cleared things up a lot.